# Is there a drivers update program for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, updates

There's a program called Driver Booster for Windows that I use sometimes to update drivers that I cannot find easily. Since I switched over to using Ubuntu for my laptop, I just use `sudo apt upgrade` for updating packages on my machine. But I'm not sure whether that will also update my drivers to the newest version. Is there a program on Ubuntu that shows me outdated drivers on my machine and let me update them?

Comment: `sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`  applies to any the system has installed, or you have added via sources.  This doesn't apply to ones you've compiled & added from source code though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux, nearly all drivers are built directly into the Linux kernel and thus are upgraded every time you update the kernel.

The exceptions, such as some WiFi NIC drivers, and GPU drivers, may or may not be upgraded with an `apt upgrade` depending on a couple factors (such as whether or not the package is "held back"). You can control the installed version of these drivers through Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers.

Comment: Thank you. That's very useful to know that I don't need to visit a bunch of different manufacturers site to download their drivers.

Comment: @Kingle My philosophy on driver updates is different from yours :) I tend to go with the *"if it ain't broke don't fix it"* train of thought.

Comment: I think this is the most idiotic thing about Linux - that you rely on the kernel for updates, It should be the responsibility of the device manufacturer to provide the updates, as the os version updates.